# Push notification using atmosphere

Tags: java, atmosphere

I am using Atmosphere RC 2.4.5(java 1.8, jsp, tomcat 8, and javascript Atmosphere client) for pushing messages from server to the clients. Everything works as expected, and didn't have any trouble with the implementation of it, but now I have doubt about the next thing:

I implemented a feature where admin user can send some notification to all users currently using the app. But if in that exact time while the message was pushing through web sockets, some user clicked link and started navigation to another page. His web socket would be closed and he would never get the message.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved using the atmosphere, so no messages would be lost.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your solution based on this page from documentation of atmosphere-js :

[Sharing connection between Browser's windows and tabs](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Sharing-connection-between-Browser's-windows-and-tabs)

> By default, the atmosphere.js library will open a new connection (based on the available transports: websocket, long-polling, streaming, sse, jsonp or ajax) every time a new window or tab is opened by the Browser. In some case it may be more efficient to share a connection between windows/tabs. To enable the mechanism, all you need to do is to set the shared property of an AtmosphereRequest object:

Here's example :

```
var request = new $.atmopshere.AtmosphereRequest();
request.shared = true;
request.transport = 'websocket'
$.atmosphere.subscribe(request);
```

One of these lines can be the solution of your problem :

```
request.shared = true;
```